# Can someone explain to me what the return type Dict[Any, Dict[Any, dict]] in Python represents?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to Python and trying to understand the different ways Dict can be used. The code I am looking at returns:

```
 Dict[Any, Dict[Any, dict]]
```

Can someone explain in simple terms what this represents?

Comment: Dicts are mappings between keys and values. In type hints, you denote the type of keys and values with `dict[key, value]`. This means you have a nested dict, like: `{key: {key: {}}}`

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) type is a constraint free type, basically anything.

[Dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) is an annotation for [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict). In your example, it is used to type values (as keys are always `Any`)

And so [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is dict without constraint, see `dict` as the same as `Dict[Any, Any]`.

Your code should return nested dicts with 3 levels of depth. For instance, it might returns `{0: {'0': {0: 0}}}`.

Be aware this is just a type hint, you can statically check with `mypy` the type hints to be coherent. But in your real code you can (you should not) completely ignore these type hints

Answer (score 2):

You are simply creating a nested dictionary!

Dictionary are Key/Value pairs and in the value, you placed another Dictionary in it.

```
main_dict = {'sub_dict_1': {'key_1' : 'value_1'},
             'sub_dict_2': {'key_2' : 'value_2'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is exactly like it sounds. You're given a key (like a word in a physical dictionary) and a value (like a definition in a physical dictionary). These can contain anything. For example, a dictionary may have a key of names 'Bob', 'Jack', 'Susan' and values of their ID Numbers.

In this case of the code you are viewing, these are nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) used to inform static typing checker ([`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/)) about value type.

In this particular case this type hint represents a `dict` (first `Dict`) with keys of any type (first `Any`) and values being dicts (nested `Dict[Any, dict]`).